# synchronous buck simulation

Tags: buck, synchronous

I got confusing result from hspice simulation but I can't get it.
the voltage at "N1"should be 4V when W1 on,and be 0 when W0 on.
but result is always 0 and pulse of negative voltage.
below is the concept pic ,code,and waveform
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like you need a body diode on both switches, especially the one in the bottom. Also, don't forget a bit of dead time between the two complementary drive signals to the switch gates.

Comment: I can't understand the code because I don't know the convention, so I should ask: Is there any dead time between the switches? Are you sure that you are not shorting the supply? Or in other words, is there any possibility that both switches can be on at the same time?

Comment: body diode may not critical since switch can have reverse current. I try to create dead time by   two control signal to.each switch but result is almost the same

Comment: What kind of switches are those? I don't have HSPICE, but the inductor-looking part seems fishy. If you don't have voltage controlled switches (but I think you should, they have been a part of SPICE since 50 years ago, or so), then just use transistors (NMOS/PMOS); it won't be an "ideal" case anymore, though.

Comment: I just noticed the reference designators: `W`. I think you are using **current**-controlled switches, not **voltage**. Look for `S` prefix.

Comment: i see ,but i used the code below to simulate, and the gXXX is the voltage controlled switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A synchronous buck converter can be easily simulated with two voltage-controlled switches across which a diode is connected. This diode is important for the low-side switch as it will immediately conduct the inductive current when the main switch opens. Then, after the deadtime is elapsed, the low-side switch is turned in zero-voltage switching (ZVS) mode:

[image]

I like the programming of the drive sources via a .VAR (in SIMPLIS) or a .PARAM statement in SPICE. You can change the duty ratio and frequency on the fly and the parameters will be automatically computed before the simulation starts:

[image]

The duty ratio is set slightly above 50% to compensate for the ohmic losses induced by the inductor equivalent series resistance (ESR) and the two switches drops. As a next step, you can replace the two sources by a proper pulse-width modulator (PWM) block with a dead time generator and start analyzing the frequency response.

Comment: ty!!! I added the reverse diode than it worked as I thought